# error: cannot access QueryBuilder Elasticserach 8.5.1

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, intellij-idea, migration

```
/Query.java:3: error: cannot access QueryBuilder
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;
                                    ^
  bad class file: /home/runner/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/8.5.1/67dbb2f5b343de39ec14b8eb1894be353343bce1/elasticsearch-8.5.1.jar(/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilder.class)
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I tried gradle clean and rebuild the project. it still happens

Comment: `class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0` this usually means you don't have the correct JAVA version. 8.5.1 requires [Java 17 or higher](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm)